# Get the difference between two dates using Nuxt and @nuxtjs/moment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs, nuxt.js, web-frontend

I'm new to Nuxt and I have a problem when I'm using this code to get the difference between two dates (user input date and now) it works but when the input date is '2020-03-31' or '2020-01-30' the console shows **NaN years NaN month NaN day**

How to fix this? What am I doing wrong?

I guess month in moment module start at 0-11 but my month input is 1-12
or can someone please show me a sample code (get different of 2 date output year, month, date)

using module : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/moment

```
methods: {
    //example input format >>> date = '2020-08-21'
    calcDate(date){
      let nowDate = moment(new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10).split('-'));
      let pickDate = moment(date.toString().substr(0, 10).split('-'));
      let dateDiff = moment.duration(nowDate.diff(pickDate));
      console.log(dateDiff.years() + ' years ' + dateDiff.months() + ' month ' + dateDiff.days() + ' day ')
    }

},
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [mention the date format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) when parsing the date

```
methods: {
    //example input format >>> date = '2020-08-21'
    calcDate(date){
      let nowDate = moment();
      let pickDate = moment(date.toString(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
      let dateDiff = moment.duration(nowDate.diff(pickDate));
      console.log(dateDiff.years() + ' years ' + dateDiff.months() + ' month ' + dateDiff.days() + ' day ')
    }

},
```